# How can i read ArrayLists within a document from Firestore cloud database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm Trying to build a restaurant app using firestore to store the orders and the users.

I tried 2 methods, first one was to write the ArrayList of orders as a Array in firestore database, but coudn't read them afterwards... 
I used `DocumentSnapshot.toObject(myclassoflist.class)` but this only worked with no array list in the document, only with values = ".."

Then I created a collection of documents (each document is an item) which contains the array as simple values 
To understand this take a look at my database
[image]

Then, to read them i first get all the document ids

```
        db.collection("orders").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                    documentsIDs.add(document.getId());

                }
                Integer allIdsD = task.getResult().size();

                if (allIdsD.equals(documentsIDs.size())) {
                    readDocs();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Then for each document id, i created 3 more `db.collection(collection).get()` in order to get the inside of each document within the subcollection, using again the function `DocumentSnapshot.toObject(myclass.class)`.

The problem here is that it takes ~0.8 secs to get a complete order from the database, which is a lot considering there could be like 100+ orders per day

[My project on GITHUB](https://github.com/prologikus/LimatexMM)

Examples from: LimatexMM/app/src/main/java/g3org3/limatexmm/orders.java

**EDIT:**
I also tried to write the orders as follow:

```
    orderListBig docData = new orderListBig(list, currentUser, adList, docId);
```

(list is ArrayList, currentUser, adList are objects)

```
    db.collection("orderss").document(docId).set(docData)
```

and then read it with:

```
        db.collection("orderss").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                    orderListBig ahah = document.toObject(orderListBig.class);

                    allOrders.add(ahah); (ArrayList of ordersListBig)
```

[image]

an part of my order document
[image]

Comment: You can represent your [`ArrayList` as `HashMap`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays).

Comment: Can you be more explicit ?, i tried to write the order as this:
        Map<String, Object> docData = new HashMap<>();
        docData.put("empty", "fill");

        docData.put("orderitems", list);
        docData.put("user", currentUser);
        docData.put("additional", adList);

        db.collection("orderss").document(docId).set(docData)

where list is a ArrayList<class> and currentUser, adlist are declared as class currentuser, ...

Comment: Since I don't know how your `Order` looks like, I'll explain on simple `ArrayList`. If you have list `["a", "b", "c"]`, that's probably going to be saved in Firebase as `{0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"}`, which is not going to be great once you start deleting data. If you delete `"b"`, you're left with `{0: "a", 2: "c"}` and that's not continuous data aka array. Instead, you can save your list as `HashMap<String, Boolean>` which would be `{"a": true, "b": true, "c": true}` and now you are not limited when deleting data.

Comment: Perhaps, in your case it would we `HashMap<OrderDocId, Boolean>`, where `OrderDocId` is probably `String`.

Comment: In my case, the data that will be stored will be either deleted, either requested (read), and the order is much complex than a simple list 
in the first photo that i posted you can see an example of how the data is stored in different collections and in the last photo is the same data but stored in one single document, that document i cannot read with toObject using the same class as i used to write it

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays) regarding the use of arrays in Cloud Firestore you need to know that:

> Although Cloud Firestore can store arrays, **`it does not support`** querying array members or updating single array elements.

If you only want to get the entire `orderList` array and get the value of, let's say `itemMore`, you need to get the reference of that particular document and then iterate over a `Map` like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = documentSnapshot.getData();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().equals("itemMore")) {
        Log.d("TAG", entry.getValue().toString());
    }
}
```

But note, even if `orderList` object is stored in the database as an array, `entry.getValue()` returns an `ArrayList`, not an `array`.

I better approach for your use-case, would be if you consider this alternative database structure, where each item is the key in a map and all values are true:

```
orderList: {
    "itemMore": true,
    "itemMoreValue": true,
    "itemMoreOtherValue": true
}
```

Bafta! ;)

Comment: It's pretty difficult for me to fully understand but you're saying that i cannot read an entire array from firestore ?, I don't need to update the array because it's just an list of items that a customer bought, what i need to update is just a value from an "object"(as stored in firestore)
ps: my orderList doesn't look like your example, as you can see in my last image, there are 2 objects, additionalList and user, which contains infos about order date/status and the client, orderList which is a list of objects

Comment: I didn't say that you cannot read, I said that can read, but the object that you see it's an array is actually an ArrayList. The title of your question is: "How can i read ArrayLists"? Now you are asking how to update. Ok, which value from which object you want to update?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, my question is still how to read my firestore document with a single command, since (as you can see in my post) i've only managed to read it using multiple documents,collections and read documents that only contains value = value(strings, numbers) but this lead to ~ 1 second time of reading for just one order. My document, as seen in the images, contains 1 string(obtional, docid), 2 objects (containing strings, numbers) and 1 list of multiple objects

Comment: Using my solution above, did not helped you at all? Have you tried it?

Comment: I want to read the whole document and get it as the same object as i wrote it(orderListBig), not just a value...

Comment: When you are using the code from the latest edit what is wrong? Assuming you are using `db.collection("orders")` and not `db.collection("orderss")` (double s) as you mentioned?

Comment: In collection orders the data is stored in multiple collections inside the main document (like you can see in the first image), in the collection orderss the data is stored as a single object (see after "EDIT:" tag in my post)

Comment: It's to bload what you ask can cannot be writed in a single comment. Beside that, if I were you, I would change the database structure to a more simple one that can contain only a single collection and more simple properties.